# CircleCI - How to test on IE11?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, testing, circleci

I have an Angular CLI App and I'm using CircleCI 2.0 configuration. I want to test my app against IE11. Relevant part of my `karma.conf.ts`:

```
plugins: [
  ...
  require('karma-ie-launcher')
  ...
]
browsers: ['IE']
```

Relevant Circle CI config:

```
test:
    working_directory: ~/app
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.2.1-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: npm test -- --single-run --progress=false --code-coverage --log-level=DEBUG
```

I get the following error in CircleCI Logs:

```
13 08 2017 16:25:17.085:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for IE browser on your platform.
  Please, set "IE_BIN" env variable.
```

**1: Is IE included in the `circleci/node:8.2.1-browsers` image? If not, how do I install it?**

**2. What would be the value of `IE_BIN` environment variable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

CircleCI 2.0 runs Linux based operating systems/containers. Internet Explorer (IE) runs only on Windows.

There are 3rd-party services that you could offload IE testing to.

- Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI